# How do I package Mono applications for Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono, debian

Are there any guidelines or tools for packaging Mono applications for Debian/Ubuntu? Like where to put Assemblies that ship with the application etc.

Answer (score 5):

Mono has some general guidelines about packaging, but these are not specific to Debian/Ubuntu who may do things differently:

http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines:Application_Deployment

Answer (score 0):

There's, of course, the [Debian CLI Policy](http://pkg-mono.alioth.debian.org/cli-policy/index.html). It's a dry read, but will probably clarify some details as to where are some files expected to be deployed.

I must confess I still have some doubts after reading that, but the next step would probably be look into the package sources of some CLI application already in the distribution, like keepass2.